# Archive manager explorer fetches wrong version of component

Tags: 2011, archival

I am implementing archiving in our project.

I noticed that when I update a component present in already archived page, and I try to open the component from artifacts list of the page in archive manager explorer, the latest version of the component is opened. I didn't publish the component or the page after updating.

Is this expected behavior?

How can I fetch actual version of the component that was archived?

Answer (score 5):

Archive Manager takes snapshots of content as they pass through the deployer, so this makes it impossible to take a snapshot of something that was not published, because Archive Manager has no other way to access the content.

This process is explained pretty well on the diagram in [this page](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Archive%20Manager%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-2F36B0FD-23D1-425A-98FA-1C03D5812D36) (login required) and as you can see, Archival runs as a deployer module.

Do you perhaps have an event system that auto-publishes content?

Another option is to look at the Archive Database and logs, this should shed some light into what is being archived and when.

Answer (score 1):

Archive Manager Explorer provides a link to the **Component** edit screen for the Component that is present on the page and not (as you'd like) to a specific **version**. So what you are seeing is indeed the expected behavior.

From the Component edit window, you can open the version history for that Component and look up the correct version by its date.